# How to manage both server and client side program in one android application

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have goggled many sites but i didn't get any solution,instead i got the solution like in the same application one should be acting as server and other as client only i don't want such kind of solutions....

Answer (score 0):

In your clent class open a SeverSocket that listens to any coming connection. You should do this in a thread:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket;
try 
{
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(100);
    while(true) 
    {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();  // accept connection
        MyThread t = new MyThread(socket);    // make a thread of it
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Thread t handles the new coming socket.